# Optimising range/wildcard search on encrypted columns.

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, encryption

I have couple of requirements which don't really play well with each other:

1. Encrypt the first name, last name, DOB along with few other columns in a table (database is Sql Server).
2. Perform range/wildcard search on some of those encrypted columns. i.e. select * from table where first_name like '%jo%' and last_name like '%exceptional%'.

I know that I need to decrypt the whole table then perform the search which is painfully slow. But somehow I need to optimise the search.

Now I can think of doing the search either on the database or inside the application using dataset/ Linq etc.

So, which approach will be relatively faster? Is there any other way of optimising this?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2008? Can you use TDE?

Comment: We are using Sql Server Web Edition. I am trying to convince the management about TDE. But it is very expensive for us, almost 15K GBP/year.

Comment: Your requirements are contradicting each other. You can either cell encrypt your data, **or** you can use range searches. Never both. Picking one means sacrificing the other and *there is no workaround*. Using hashes for searches can, at best, provide singleton lookup (probes) but never range scans.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into Data Hashing.  Hashing can allow you to do searches without having to decrypt every row.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlsecurity/archive/2011/08/26/data-hashing.aspx

Comment: Creating Hash or MAC won't be suitable in this context as hashing can be used for equality search not wildcard/range search.